# Some confusion in regard with node pointer syntax in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

so I am new to low-level language. And I was going through some learning materials for C, and I could not really distinguish the difference between the following expressions.

```
struct Node *temp;
struct Node *head;

//expression 1
temp->next = head;
//expression 2
temp = head;
```

Don't the two expressions mean the same thing which is directing the pointer of the temp node towards WHERE the pointer of the head node points to?

Comment: Assuming that `next` is a member of the `Node` structure and have the type `struct Node *`, then you have two different pointers. They can point to the same location, or to different locations. It's like two different variables. If you had e.g. `struct Node *temp1, *temp2;` and then `temp1 = head; temp2 = head; ` would you still ask about the difference between the assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` is a pointer. Presumably, before your “expression 1,” it has been set to point to some node *x*. Then `temp->next = head;` sets the `next` member of *x* to `head`. It changes *x* (the `next` member in *x*). It does not change `temp`.

In contrast, `temp = head;` sets `temp` to `head`. It changes `temp`.

Comment: Yeah, I think I can clearly articulate the difference now. ```temp=head``` actually changes the address of ```temp``` whereas ```temp->next = head```means linking ```temp``` to where ```head```points to and its own address doesn't change.

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could give a more clear problem definition.

Answer (score 1):

As you have declared there, `temp` and `head` are pointers, and in the first expression the `next` value of the `temp` pointer points to `head`
whereas in the second expression you are making `temp=head`

...that does not mean that `temp` points to `head`, rather `temp` is now `head`...

Hope you get it. :)

Comment: Thank you. But sorry guys I have already clicked an check mark for a response earlier. I will give you guys a vote for sure. As you have seen, the moment when I was asking this question, there was a big mess in my head about pointer and node. Now it is much more clear.